# Masking replacing random string characters in array of objects

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [{
email: 'someemail@somedomain.net',
domain: 'somedomain',
title: 'software developer'
}];

//desired output will be something like:
var arr = [{
email: 's*m*e*a*l@s*m*d*m*i*.n*t',
domain: 's*m*d*m*i*',
title: 's*f*w*r* d*v*l*p*r'
}];
```

This can be randomly masked with * it does not need to be every second char.
Thanks!

Comment: can your array object has different properties, or only email, domain and title ?

Comment: yes it can it will have n number of properties all will be strings.

Comment: should all properties values be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could randomly change the characters and join the array back to a string.

```js
var string = 'someemail@somedomain.net';

string = Array.from(string, c => Math.random() < 0.5 ? '*' : c).join('');

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the objects and `map` over the string and change every 2nd, 3rd,... any letter to '*'

This solution is not for random, but for every 2nd, 3rd,... letter depending upon value passed to method

```js
var arr = [{
email: 'someemail@somedomain.net',
domain: 'somedomain',
title: 'software developer'
}];

function getMaskedData(d, every) {
  return [...d].map((v,i) => (i + 1) % every  == 0 ? '*' : v).join('')
}

let newObj = {}
for(let [k, v] of Object.entries(arr[0])) {
  newObj[k] = getMaskedData(v, 2)
}

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Totally flexible, even no need to worry about `key` name